# Trouble identifying hot and neutral in old house (no ground?)

Tags: wiring, switch, ceiling-fan, old-house, voltage

I am replacing a ceiling fan and did not note how it was previously wired before taking it down (i.e. which are the hot and neutral wire). The house is quite old (some parts over 100 years - including this room) and i'm not convinced there are grounds anywhere in here except our new construction areas. The switch that controls the fan has only a white and black wire attached (no ground) with the black wire on top by the ground screw and the white wire on the bottom (which i think is typical and correct - the switch is new within the last 20 years), but in the ceiling box there are a number of different white and black wires, they are grouped into three distinct twists:

1 - Two white wires and a black wire
2 - Two black wires
3 - A single black wire

I should mention that there is only one line in the switch box - it has a black wire and a white wire - they are hooked up to the switch - there is nothing else running in or through that box.

I have a multimeter and a pretty good understanding of how this all works, I've put in new outlets and switches before, but this has left me a little baffled. i'm not understanding the readings of the multimeter - since there is no ground i'm just touching the prongs to two wires at a time to see what has voltage. Here are the results:

Switch on: 1 and 3 = 0V, 1 and 2 = 120V, 2 and 3 = 120V

Switch off: 1 and 3 = 10V (ghost voltage - i ran a low impedance test on it), 1 and 2 = 120V, 2 and 3 = 80V (ghost voltage - i ran a low impedance test on it)

HOWEVER i shut the power off and did a conductivity test. When the switch was off there was no combination of wires that had conductivity, but when the switch was on I found conductivity when touching the probes to wires 1 and 3. Which confuses me because when the power is on and the switch is on there are 0V when touching the multimeter probes to those wires.

Can someone please help me understand what i should be doing to better figure this out? What am I missing/doing wrong here?

Comment: You've got 4 blacks and 2 whites. Any time there is a mixture (whites and blacks on a switch, whites and blacks connected together) that means *cables* rather than individual wires. And when there are cables, there should be exactly the same number of black wires as white wires. Which means along with whatever else may be messed up, I suspect one of the "black" wires is really an old/dirty white wire.